# QRegExp. grab all links

Tags: html, regex, qt, qregexp

I write regular expression to grab all ref links from html

```
QRegExp bodylinksrx("(<a\\s+href\\s*=\\s*[^<>]*\\s*>[^<>]*</a>)");
QStringList bodylinks;
pos = 0;
while ((pos = bodylinksrx.indexIn(htmlcode, pos)) != -1)
{
    bodylinks << bodylinksrx.cap(1);
    pos += bodylinksrx.matchedLength();
}
```

I recieve list as result:

```
("<a href="http://somehref" class="someclass">href text...</a>", "<a href="http://somehref" class="someclass">href text...</a>", ......")
```

But I need receive list with only `"http://somehref" "href text..." "http://somehref" "href text..." ....`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags or in short: HTML cannot be parsed with RegularExpressions as it is not a regular language.

Comment: I use HTML Tidy on input html.

Comment: It still doesn't magically turn HTML into a regular language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off have you [read this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) secondly if you're sure you know what you're doing and definitely know you want to do it try using lookahead and lookbehind assertions for your anchor tags.

```
((?<=<a\\s+href\\s*=\\s*[^<>]*\\s*>)[^<>]*(?=</a>))
```

EDIT: unfortunately this will not work (at least with qt4.8) as lookbehind assertions [are not supported](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html).  You could just iterate through the list created and match the desired bit with:

```
[^<>]*(?=<)
```

and use that, alternatively use the [captured texts function](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#capturedTexts) to extract the part you want which you will surround with brackets like so:

```
<a\\s+href\\s*=\\s*[^<>]*\\s*>([^<>]*)</a>
```